# Dell XPS 13 9333 display white/foggy

Tags: dell-xps, white-screen

My Dell laptop's display started flickering today. Now it has changed to a mostly-white screen except for the outer edges.

[image: white screen]

It's like this both in BIOS and Windows 10.

The warranty has expired so I'm looking at ways to fix it.

Can anyone offer any suggestions for fixing it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Is your question really "*Is this a relatively common issue*"? Or are you really wanting to ask how to fix it? In my experience, if this happens all the time (in BIOS and Windows), it is most likely a bad display.

Comment: Both, really, but ideally how to fix it!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to ask that question then.